# how to load external JS file into moodle?

Tags: moodle

how to load external JS file into moodle ?   using moodle api ,i.e moodle libraries    ..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Moodle 2.0 I have always used `$PAGE->requires->js()`.

To start with, make `$PAGE` available to your code by doing:

```
require_once($CFG->libdir . '/pagelib.php');
global $PAGE;
```

and then in your code:

```
$PAGE->requires->js( new moodle_url($CFG->wwwroot . '/blocks/your_block/script.js') );
```

It is required to put `moodle_url()` around your path!

Comment: How is using "$PAGE->requires->js()" better than directly adding "<script src=blabla>" in moodle theme php's ?

Comment: @iankit it is better (and allows pages to load much faster) for several reasons:
a) It avoids loading the same script repeatedly - if four different blocks all use jquery, there's no need to load the jquery library four times.
b) It may avoid loading it at all until it's needed - your block probably won't be clicked at all for most page loads.
c) It loads the javascript after the page is rendered, so the user doesn't get a blank screen for several seconds while all of the javascript files are loaded.
d) Moodle combines multiple javascript files, getting them in one request rather than 20.

Answer (score 0):

```
     <?php 
         //you have load $CFG , firstly check in config.php
         //after that print_r($CFG);
         //also you can use $CFG->wwwroot;

   require ('../config.php');
    require_once ($CFG->dirroot.'/login/lib.php');

//and then in your code:// after that
echo $OUTPUT->header(); ?>


<script src="<?php $CFG->wwwroot ?>/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php $CFG->wwwroot ?>js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"    type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="<?php $CFG->wwwroot ?>js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<?php $PAGE->requires->js(new moodle_url($CFG->wwwroot.'/blocks/your_block/script.js')); ?>
```

Comment: could you explain more, where to put the js file?