# How to load external JS file and call in <script></script> on page for Moodle?

Tags: javascript, php, require, moodle

I arelady found [how to load external JS file into moodle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915258/how-to-load-external-js-file-into-moodle) but it doesn't solve my problem.

I got an external JS file must be loaded as it's the VOD service's player.

Having to call it in `<script></script>` in my course's video page like so,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 (function(){ 
   var option ={"auto_play":"0","file_id":"someid","app_id":"some_app_id","width":0,"height":0,"https":1}; 
   new qcVideo.Player( "id_video_container_someid" /* this is the div id */, option ); 
 })() 
 </script>
```

So this `qcVideo` is `Uncaught ReferenceError: qcVideo is not defined` as Moodle uses require.js to load js files, and I'm not familiar with that.

The js file is [h5connect.js](https://qzonestyle.gtimg.cn/open/qcloud/video/h5/h5connect.js).

I tried to put it in my theme's `javascript` folder and `amd/src` folder. and in theme's config.php like this `$THEME->javascript_footer=array('h5connect');`
 both not working.

So what exactly I should do to make this `qcVideo.Player` work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first include the JS file and then you can put the  tag. Then it should work.

`$PAGE->requires->js('/local/programmanagement/module.js');`
Put your script tag after it. It seems u are putting script tag before the js lib loaded.